# AVCaptureMetadataOutput change area of scanning

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm trying AVCaptureMetadataOutput for scanning barcodes. I want to scan barcode from the whole **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer** but it scans only from the center point of the **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer**, i want to change the **AVCaptureMetadataOutput** rect and i used the following code for that but it did not change the rect.

```
CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];

CGRect visibleMetadataOutputRect = [_prevLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:layerRect];
_output.rectOfInterest = visibleMetadataOutputRect;
```

i also provide the landscape scanning so i am transfroming the layer when user change the orientation.

Comment: I have same issue using above code.I also find same code from one blog and its not working as it is written in blog.Let me know when you found any.